# Unexpected additional final step with numpy.arange function

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to implement a function to calculate a Spline interpolation of a known function.
Therefore in the first step I want to calculate some of the known support points. The amount of support points shall be dynamic. To achieve this I calculate the step width and there I get a behavior I can't explain myself. For 15 distances between 16 support points the `numpy.arange` functions returns 17 values. For most other cases I tested it returns the distances + 1 values that I expect.

Any idea what I am overlooking?

Find my code and running results below:

```
# Parameter

n = 15
x0 = -5
xend = 5

def xy_support(n,x0,xend) :
    x_support = np.arange(x0,xend+((xend-x0)/n),((xend-x0)/n))
    y_support = f(x_support)
    return x_support,y_support

x,y = xy_support(n,x0,xend)

print(x)
print(y)
```

Output x:

> [-5.         -4.33333333 -3.66666667 -3.         -2.33333333 -1.66666667
> -1.         -0.33333333  0.33333333  1.          1.66666667  2.33333333
> 3.          3.66666667  4.33333333  5.          5.66666667]

I would expect the last value to be 5. This is what I get for most other inputs n like 6,9,100.

Comment: Inaccuracies from float point values are to blame. You can see that the step is 0.666..., but the endpoint is 5.666...667, causing the last step to be made when you expect it to terminate. From the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html): _"When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, it is often better to use [numpy.linspace](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)."_

Comment: I think the comment above is correct: with `stp = (xend-x0)/n` I can check `xend + stp > -5+stp*15` and it evaluates to True. So it's stopping one more piece further than it should. There's a warning in the documentation about this as well: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal This is correct. Further down in the reference there is also a warning that the function is not numerical stable under all circumstances. Using the ´´numpy.linspace´´ function solved the issue. Also it gives better control over the endpoint in my opionion.

Comment: @MarcNu If this question is solved then you should mark it as closed.